# How to filter and dispatch my data I receive from async/await call

Tags: reactjs, api, filter, async-await, dispatch

I'm building a stock market app project in React and ran into a problem I have been trying to solve all day with no success. Could really use some help because I know I am close. The code is attached in a picture, and I'll also post here:

```js
// Search Stocks
  
const searchStocks = async () => {

  // await data from API
   
  const res = await axios(`https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/searchquery=${state.text}&exchange=NASDAQ`);
   
  const res2 = await axios(`https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/searchquery=${state.text}&exchange=NYSE`);

   // after data has returned in variables, then filter results
    
  const filteredResults = [...res, ...res2].filter(stock => stock.symbol.includes(state.text.toUpperCase()))

    // dispatch to have filtered results added to state to show the user
  dispatch({
    type: SEARCH_STOCKS,
    payload: filteredResults
  });
};
```

So I have double and triple checked my methods that I am filtering the data correctly. I know the logic is sound. The problem I am running into is I don't want the code below my await functions to execute until I get my responses. I have tried all kinds of variations using .then() methods without success. How can I do this properly?

Screenshot: [image: searchStocks]

Comment: How do you call `searchStocks`? The `await` should work and your filter will be called once both awaits are resolved. So I don't see the problem at the moment. Maybe the function is called too often. Have you checked how many times it is called?

Comment: Its not. I commented out the 'await axios' lines and the filteredResults lines and tried just giving filteredResults the data straight from the API in the format of [{Stock Object 1}, {Stock Object 2}] and it works smoothly. My error messages when I run the code above is below and it also complains about passing map value of null in my code as well:                                                                                        StocksState.js:88 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
    at searchStocks (StocksState.js:88)

Answer (score 0):

the await is all good, probably just check whether the query gave any actual data

```
    // Search Stocks

    const searchStocks = async () => {

      // await data from API

      const res = await axios(`https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/searchquery=${state.text}&exchange=NASDAQ`);

      const res2 = await axios(`https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/searchquery=${state.text}&exchange=NYSE`);

       // after data has returned in variables, then filter results

      let filteredResults = [];
      if(res1 && res2)
          filteredResults = [...res, ...res2].filter(stock => stock.symbol.includes(state.text.toUpperCase()))

        // dispatch to have filtered results added to state to show the user
      dispatch({
        type: SEARCH_STOCKS,
        payload: filteredResults
      });
    };
```

EDIT: I tested it n ran into a CORS policy case in Firefox, whereas in Chrome I didn't, you might wanna look that up, it might be that why the axios gets don't return the proper data

Comment: If you ran the code above, there is a ? between search and query. Then, it returns the proper data. The data I would received from res and res2, I ran in the code below in my jsconsole, and it worked. But, whenever I run the same code above in my post, I get the promise error coming from the line of code storing the data in const filteredResults.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code in react waiting and filtering the data for displaying:

I created a jsfiddle if you need: https://jsfiddle.net/prem7qdx/2/

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: null
    }
  }
 }
 

class SearchForm extends React.Component {

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = [...event.target.elements].reduce((data, element) => {
     if (element.name && element.value) {
        data[element.name] = element.value;
      }
  
      return data;
    }, {});
    
   let url = `https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/search?query=${data.query}&&limit=10`;
    if(data.exchange !== 'ALL') {
     url = `https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/search?query=${data.query}&&limit=10&&exchange=${data.exchange}`
    }
    

     axios.get(url)
    .then((res) => { 
    
     let array = res.data;
      
      $('#foo').empty();

      var list = $('<ul/>');  
      for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
         let item = $('<li/>');
          item.append(array[i].symbol+' | '+ array[i].name+' | '+ array[i].stockExchange );
         list.append(item);

      }
 
   $('#foo').append(list);
   
    })
  };
  

  render() {
    return (
      <form action="/search" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" name="query" />
        <select name="exchange" defaultValue={'ALL'}>
          <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
          <option value="NASDAQ">NYSE</option>
          <option value="NYSE">NASDAQ</option>
          <option value="AMEX">AMEX</option>
          <option value="EURONEXT">EURONEXT</option>
          <option value="TSX">TSX</option>
          <option value="MUTUAL_FUND">MUTUAL_FUND</option>
          <option value="COMMODITY">COMMODITY</option>
          <option value="INDEX">INDEX</option>
          <option value="CRYPTO">CRYPTO</option>
          <option value="FOREX">FOREX</option>
          <option value="TSX">TSX</option>
          <option value="AMEX">AMEX</option>
          <option value="EURONEXT">EURONEXT</option>
        </select>
        <button>Find</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SearchForm />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.4/dist/global/Rx.umd.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.12.0/axios.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react-dom.js"></script>


<div id='app'>
</div>
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responding guys! I talked with my bootcamp instructor and he helped me out and got the code working. It actually had to do with putting 'res.data' and 'res2.data' into the array returned to filteredResults. I also manually passed the text to searchStocks as well because for some reason, setting the text in my state was 1 character behind (so I passed e.target.value directly to the searchStocks function. Solution below:

`const searchStocks = async sym => {
    const res = await axios.get(`
https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/search?query=${sym}&exchange=NASDAQ
    `);
    const res2 = await axios.get(`
https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/search?query=${sym}&exchange=NYSE
    `);
    const filteredResults = [...res.data, ...res2.data].filter(stock =>
      stock.symbol.includes(sym.toUpperCase())
    );
    dispatch({
      type: SEARCH_STOCKS,
      payload: filteredResults
    });
  };`